# value of argc when * is passed as one of the arguments calling a program in c

Tags: c++, c, bash

There is an abnormality in the value of argc when '*' is passed as one of the arguments calling a program in c.
I made a simple code in c and saved it as 'test2.c'.Here is the following code of 'test2.c'---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
printf("%d\n",argc);return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and call it as--

```
dev@ubuntu:~$ gcc test2.c -o t
dev@ubuntu:~$ ./t *
31
```

So, i am getting the argument count value as 31; whereas if '*' is replaced by any other binary operator ; the value of  argc is 2(which is also logically correct).

```
dev@ubuntu:~$ ./t +
2
```

I am not able to fathom why is it so....and there is one more interesting thing.when '-*' is used in place of '*';the answer is 2(which is again logically correct)

```
dev@ubuntu:~$ ./t -*
2
```

Can anyone help me in this;thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its just the shell expansion. The shell will expand `*` to the filenames (directories included) in the current directory in which the program is executing.

`+` or `;` does not have special interpretations therefore they are considered as normal strings, but `*` has special interpretation, thus it is expanded to the list of all files in current directory, which is passed to your program.

Try using

`./t '*'` or `./t \*`

This stops special interpretation of `*`. The first one used the bash (<strike>looks like</strike> you are in bash) single quote, which does not make any special interpretation inside the patterns in the quote, and the next one uses escape sequence.

Comment: Also, the string `-*` will expand to a list of filenames that begin with a hyphen if any exist. If not, it will be left intact literally unless `shopt -s nullglob` is in effect, then you get a null string. Double quotes also protect glob characters, but they do allow variable and parameter expansions.

Answer (score 6):

It's the shell that expands `*` to the list of files in the current directory. Print out the `argv` to see that this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

`argc` will always give you the number of elements in `argv[]`.
The arguments passed to `argv[]` will always contain at least the name of the executable so `argc` is always the number of arguments + 1.

The `*` case is although special, since your shell will expand `*` to all files and directories within your local directory. If you want `*` to not be expanded pass it as `"*"` with the double-quotes.

Try `echo *` vs `echo "*"` in your shell to see how `*` gets expanded.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the shell expanding the star operator `*` to the current directory from where you are executing this program.

There are several expansions performed before the shell initiates execution, for example `~` (tilde), `{}` (braces) and `$` (parameters), of course depending on your operating system. You can find the GNU list of expansions in the link below.

[GNU BASH Manual - 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Tip: If you had printed the values of your arguments you would probably see a list of directories and files, and the argument count 'argc' would change depending on which directory you execute from.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yep, and many more. I can write them all in the examples if that would clarify the answer, but the principle is the same - the executing environment has some reserved patterns that it evaluates out before it starts.